# SELECT query for checking duplicates without input

Tags: php, mysql, database

It is the first time I´m using `SELECT` queries without having an input. I would like to check a table for duplicates. As a result I only need to count the result.

So I have this:

```
SELECT 
       `field a`, `field b`, `field c` 
FROM 
        table 
WHERE 
        `a` AND `b` AND `c` 
GROUP BY
    duplicates
HAVING
    COUNT(duplicates) > 1
```

would this check the table for duplicates when the structure is like:

```
field a |  field b  | field c
  a          b          c
  a          b          c
  d          e          f
```

And how can I get the result? Would it be just `num_rows` or do I get an integer as a result back from the query?

Normally I use `num_rows` to fetch the result from the query like that:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT ...");
$result = $query->num_rows;
if ($result !== 0 ){do something}
```

There usually should be a difference between `num_rows` and the result because if I would count by using `num_rows` it will return `2` because 2 have the condition `a AND b AND c`so I would think that the query from above would return `1` as a result for `1` duplicate found. Or am I wrong?

Thanks alot.

Comment: I think the `WHERE` clause there is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define as duplicate two records having the same A,B, and C, then you could use a query like this:

```
SELECT A, B, C, COUNT(*) counter
FROM `MYTABLE`
GROUP BY A,B,C
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Considering your table has 3 items like in your question, your result would be:

```
 A  |  B  |  C  | counter
 ---+-----+-----+--------
'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 2
```

To fetch the results in PHP:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $a = $row['A'];
    $b = $row['B'];
    $c = $row['C'];
    $counter = $row['counter'];
    // Do something with your values
}
```

Please consider to use mysqli or PDO. A good starting point: [mysqli or PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons)

Comment: hello and thanks. sorry for this but how can i fetch the result? so that i can work with the result? normally i use num_rows to the query but would this be correct because the query has already the condition > 1.

Comment: You mean how do you fetch results from PHP or from mysql?

Comment: hello, this is still not what i´m looking for. i'm sorry. language difficulties. have a look at my table. (a AND b AND c) is exactly two times in that db. so the query should count duplicate = yes (as a result -> 1). your table has all different values because of (a1 OR a2 AND b AND c). hope its gettin clear now. thanks alot.

Comment: It is clear what you mean. Group by allows only different results. I updated the result

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I quite understand the question, but if you want to display values and counts where more than one row exists with the same values of all three fields you may require something like...

```
SELECT FIELD_A, FIELD_B, FIELD_C, COUNT(*)
    FROM MY_TABLE
    GROUP BY FIELD_A, FIELD_B, FIELD_C
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: hello and thanks. sorry for this but how can i fetch the result? so that i can work with the result? normally i use num_rows to the query but would this be correct because the query has already the condition > 1.

Comment: @bonny, I don't have a working example to hand, but if I rightly recall you will need to call `mysqli_fetch_array` on your `$query` object.

Comment: hello, this is still not what i´m looking for. i'm sorry. language difficulties. have a look at my table. (a AND b AND c) is exactly two times in that db. so the query should count duplicate = yes (as a result -> 1).